# Change tr color on checkbox checked in knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have created a table structure like this:

```
<table><tr data-bind="css: {success: status}">
         <td>
          <input type="checkbox" onclick="this.disabled = 'disabled';" data-bind="checked: status, disable: status, click: $root.UpdateStatus" />
         </td>
         <td>
            <span style="width: 80%" data-bind="text: goals" />
         </td>
         <td>
            <input type="text" style="width: 80%" data-bind="value: notes , event: { blur: $root.UpdateNote}" />
         </td>
        </tr></table>
```

In this table, one checkbox is there in every row. My problem is i want to change the row color when checkbox is checked. I have done css binding in tr, but its working if i reload the page again.
This is [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/gkyGN/), but its not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cleaned up your fiddle and made it work:

http://jsfiddle.net/vyshniakov/gkyGN/3/

EDIT

For mapping data from server use `arrayMap` function from `ko.utils`:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/test.html',
        success: function(data) { // in data should come tblGoals.
            var mappedData = ko.utils.arrayMap(data, function(item) {
                // Change property names if necessary 
                return new Goal(data.GoalId, data.Goals, data.Notes, data.Status);
            });

            var viewModel = new ViewModel(mappedData);
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        }
    });
```

Comment: As i am a beginner to knockout, can you help me, how to get like this in javascript file:
var viewModel = new ViewModel([new Goal(9466, "Make my trip for kasmir.", "done dona done", true), new Goal(5647, "Learn knockout.", "dream", false)]);
As i am doing $.ajax call to get tblGoals.

Comment: Thx for your valuable Answer...I have a send button on the top of the table. I need to get the checked item on the click event of that button also i need to enable the button only when any of the checkbox in the table is selected otherwise the button should be disabled.